# Convergence or Absolute convergence?

Tags: integration

I need a help with somthing:
I need to tell if these two integrals are Convergence\Absolute convergence:

$\int _1^{\infty }\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2-x+1}}dx$, $\int _0^{\infty \:}\:\frac{\left(x^{\frac{1}{4}}+1\right)\cdot \sin\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)}{x}dx$
Now I compute this and I find that both converge. But I don't know how to check
if it is also Absolute convergence.
Thanks.

Comment: Im really sorry but I can not see any absolute function that I can compare with. And how it can help me that I know the integrals converge?

Comment: Thanks for the help!Are you sure if the integrand  is non negetavie i can tell that it is Absolute convergence?

Comment: How did you "compute this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the hint about the second integral was misleading. Here is a better one:

Notice that
\begin{align*} 
\int_0^\infty (x^{-3/4} + x^{-1})\sin(2x^{1/2})
&= \int_0^\infty \frac12 x^{-1/2} \cdot 2 (x^{-1/4} + x^{-1/2})\sin(2x^{1/2}) \\
&= \int_0^\infty 2(t^{-2} + t^{-1})\sin(2t).
\end{align*}
Now, $\int_0^\infty t^{-1}\sin(2t)$ does not converge absolutely.

Comment: Got it!!! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint on the first one: The integrand is nonnegative, so convergence and absolute convergence are the same. For large $x,$ the integrand is on the order of $1/x^{3/2}.$ So the integral over $[2,\infty),$ say, converges. For the integral over $[1,2],$ the problem is that near $1,$ both numerator and denominator in the integrand $\to 0$ at $1.$ You'll have to figure out what's going on there. Is the integrand bounded? Blowing up in a convergent manner? Blowing up in a divergent manner?